# Difference in dates in SAS by group

Tags: sas

Consider a data set  `test`  in the following form:

```
 Group   Date
  1      05JAN2014
  1      08JAN2014
  1      14JAN2014
  2      05JAN2013
  2      10FEB2015
  2      27FEB2015
```

I want to calculate the difference in dates based on group. The code below takes the difference between every two dates:

```
  data test;
  datediff = dif(Date);
  run;
```

How would I only take the difference between dates in one group? Moreover, is there a way to take a difference between the last and first dates in each group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with this:

```
 data test;
  datediff = dif(Date);
  run;
```

Let's address your isues one at a time.  First, adding a `set` statement and a `by` statement, we can also add `first` and `last` to allow you to determine where you are in the group.  This assumes it's already sorted `by group`.

```
data test2;
  set test;
  by group;
  datediff=dif(date);
run;
```

This doesn't work any differently (assuming you had the set statement originally, anyway).  But now, you have some new options.

First, while you can use `dif`, I recommend the `retain` method for this.  You can more easily see what it's doing, and avoid some common pitfalls: particularly, `lag` and `dif` don't actually compare to a previous record - they create a queue and compare to that, which can lead to complications when using conditional statements.

```
data test2;
  set test;
  by group;
  retain last_date;
  if first.group then last_date=0;
  datediff = date - last_date;
  output;
  last_date = date;
run;
```

This does the same thing as before - compares the previous value to the current value - but makes it a bit easier to see, and we add in an option to reset the `last_date` variable when `first.group` is true - meaning we're on the first row of a new value of group. I won't drop any of these intermediate variables, but in production code you can and should.  `retain` means the value will persist across rows (instead of being reset every time you get a new row).

Now that you have one variable tracking the previous row's value of `date`, it's pretty easy hopefully to see how we can also do this for the first->last difference.

```
data test2;
  set test;
  by group;
  retain last_date orig_date;
  if first.group then do;
    last_date=0;
    orig_date=date;  **new;
  end;
  datediff = date - last_date; 
  if last.group then group_datediff = date-orig_date;  **new;
  output;
  last_date = date;
run;
```

Now we've done the same thing as before - but we're resetting the orig_date each time we see `first.group` and calculating group_datediff when we hit `last.group`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method using `lag` and the new `ifn` function, (`ifn` is included in SAS 9.2 or later).  Be a little careful with the lag function, as it can sometimes produce some unexpected results.  See [this paper](http://howles.com/saspapers/CC33.pdf) for more detail on it.

```
*Data must be sorted to use BY groups;
proc sort data=have; by group date;run;

data want;
    set have;
    by group;
    dateDiff = ifn(first.group, . , dif(date));

    retain firstDate;
    if first.group then firstDate = date;
    if last.group then dateDiff_all = date - firstDate;
run;
```

Comment: You could calculate dateDiff by using the `dif` function instead of getting the lagged date and subtracting it from the current date (`dateDiff = ifn(first.group, . , dif(date));`

Comment: Good thought @Keith - edited to be slighlty more elegant :-).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using proc sql and a group by statement with summary functions min and max.

This will get you the difference in each group for the first and last dates.

Technically it will get you the difference in the smallest and largest dates, but you dates are in chronological order so it will work for this data.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as select
    group,
    max(date) - min(date) as datediff
    from have 
    group by group;
quit;
```

Comment: @Joe This works fine in most SQL variants I've used (just tested in mySQL and MSSQL to make sure I wasn't going crazy).  I'm not sure what you are trying to say, as the select *does* match the group by... (ie. select=group, group by=group).

Comment: Hmm.  I must have misread this - originally I read it as select *.  Oops.